# hibernate too many sql

Tags: sql, hibernate

i have test1 class  and test2 class

they are one to one and the fetch type is lazy.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test1")
public class Test1 {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "test2_id")
    private Test2 test2;

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "test2")
public class Test2 {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "test2")

    ...

}
```

i want to get all records from database :

```
    Criteria dc2 =
    sessionFactory. getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Test1.class,"mr");
    List<Test1> reports2= dc2.list();
    for(Test1 test:reports2){
        test.getTest2().getName();
    }
```

but my console show the sql is:

```
   Hibernate: select this_.id as id18_0_, this_.name as name18_0_, this_.test2_id as test3_18_0_ from test1 this_
   Hibernate: select test2x0_.id as id19_1_, test2x0_.name as name19_1_, test1x1_.id as id18_0_, test1x1_.name as name18_0_, test1x1_.test2_id as test3_18_0_ from test2 test2x0_ left outer join test1 test1x1_ on test2x0_.id=test1x1_.test2_id where test2x0_.id=?
   Hibernate: select test1x0_.id as id18_0_, test1x0_.name as name18_0_, test1x0_.test2_id as  test3_18_0_ from test1 test1x0_ where test1x0_.test2_id=?
```

because the fetch is lazy ,i  think the sql is right,

and i change the fetch type to FetchType.EARGER

```
Hibernate: select this_.id as id18_1_, this_.name as name18_1_, this_.test2_id as test3_18_1_, test2x2_.id as id19_0_, test2x2_.name as name19_0_ from test1 this_ left outer join test2 test2x2_ on this_.test2_id=test2x2_.id
Hibernate: select test1x0_.id as id18_1_, test1x0_.name as name18_1_, test1x0_.test2_id as test3_18_1_, test2x1_.id as id19_0_, test2x1_.name as name19_0_ from test1 test1x0_ left outer join test2 test2x1_ on test1x0_.test2_id=test2x1_.id where test1x0_.test2_id=?
```

i do not understand the second sql,it waste of my time

if i have 10000 records and it will circle 10000 times.

how can i resole it ? get all records in times?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the setFetchMode as Join...For example

```
 Criteria dc2 = sessionFactory. getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Test1.class,"mr");
 dc2.setFetchMode("test2", FetchMode.JOIN)
    List<Test1> reports2= dc2.list();
    for(Test1 test:reports2){
        test.getTest2().getName();
    }
```

In this way Hibernate should fill the test2 object with one query; honestly I can't say about performances since in this scenario more data will be loaded from the DB

I hope it helps

Angelo